# How to subtract the value of another row depends on Category column in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

Here is the photo explanation
[image]

I want to show the NewLinePrice in "Other Service", the value will subtract the value of "Graphic Design", so the first column will show ‭1152245‬ and so on. 
So far i've tried to defined the new column "NewLinePrice", the following is the formula but not work

```
NewLinePrice =
       Var category = 'Group-dtl'[ProductCategoryName]
       var graphic_line_price = CALCULATE(SUM('Group-dtl'[LinePrice]),FILTER('Group-dtl', 'Group-dtl'[ProductCategoryName] = "Graphic Design"))
       var graphic_line_price_temp = IF(category = "Graphic Design", 'Group-dtl'[LinePrice], 0)
       //var graphic_line_price = 1
       Var pre_result = IF(category = "Other Service", 'Group-dtl'[LinePrice] - graphic_line_price, BLANK())
       Var result = IF(pre_result > 0, pre_result, BLANK())
    return result
```

Anyone have ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend some time to find the answer for your question, at the end I discover that to achiever your outcome, you cannot perform the calculation within the original but to create a new table, the reason is unknown, however at least it is achievable, see my answer below and accept if help, appreciate my hardworking :)

This is my original table name [Sheet1]

[image]

First I create a new table based on the original table

```
Table = 
ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(Sheet1[Product Name]),
                    "Sales",CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[Amount]),
                        FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[Product Name]=EARLIER(Sheet1[Product Name]))))
```

From the new table, I add new column using the following formula to return different value only for "Other Service"

```
New Line1 = 
Var ServiceValue = CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[Amount]),Sheet1[Product Name] = "Other Service")
Var graphicValue = CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[Amount]),Sheet1[Product Name] = "Graphic Design")
Var charge = ServiceValue - graphicValue
return
if('Table'[Product Name] = "Other Service", charge,'Table'[Sales])
```

Here is new table with updated value:
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, i've already find out another answer by using measure 
test1 = 
IF(FIRSTNONBLANK('Group-dtl'[ProductCategoryName],1) = "Other Service",
SUM('Group-dtl'[LinePrice]) - CALCULATE (SUM('Group-dtl'[LinePrice]),'Group-dtl'[ProductCategoryName] = "Graphic Design"),
SUM('Group-dtl'[LinePrice]) )

i'll also study your answer

Comment: Nice to hear different solution, especially if new table no need to be created :)